# pyspark: Sort a PyhonRDD using the object attribute

Tags: sorting, pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I have a `result` RDD, which is created using `pyspark.mllib.fpm`

The `result` RDD looks like:

```
print(result)
result.take(5) 

PythonRDD[32] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48
Out[18]:
[FreqSequence(sequence=[['John']], freq=18980),
 FreqSequence(sequence=[['Mary']], freq=106),
 FreqSequence(sequence=[['John-Mary']], freq=381),
 FreqSequence(sequence=[['John-Ann']], freq=158),
 FreqSequence(sequence=[['Ann']], freq=433)]
```

How do I sort the above `result` RDD based on the `freq` attribute? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keyfunc` argument:

```
rdd.sortBy(lambda x: x.frequency)
```

Comment: doesn't work with "ImportError: No module named 'UserString' " Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyfunc argument:

```
rdd.sortBy(lambda x: x.freq)
```